# How to redirect after MS Live ID authentication

Tags: azure, wif, acs, windows-live-id, ws-federation

I'm developing an ASP.NET web-application, that is hosted on Azure and used Windows Identity Framework for authentication.

The question is: How to handle response from Identity Provider (MS Live ID)?

I found that config element  wsFederation contains reply attribute for this goal, but after setting it to reply="http://localhost:64911/Pages/HandleUserLogin.aspx" it hasn't any effect.

In audienceUris section added record for "http://localhost:64911/".

Any ideas about how to handle response after user was logged in would be appreciated.

Comment: Can we confirm you are not using the Windows Azure Access Control Service (ACS) in this solution?

Comment: No, I'm using Windows Azure Access Control Service (ACS) in this solution.

Comment: When you say response what do you mean, the user will be redirected to the IDP (Live) and then they sign in, ACS will then redirect back to your Relying Party return URL set in the Azure ACS Portal, you then use WIF to extract that claim and do what ever you need to do in your app, am I reading this wrong?